# How to store a value from scalar function in a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to writte a unit test as show bellow:

```
-- Test name
     SET @TestName        = 'EastersMonday'
     -- Set unit-test StartTime
     SET @UnitTestStart    = GETDATE()
     -- Result
     SET @RequiredResult      = 20180402
     -- Method call
     SET @FunctionResult = DWH_Staging.dim.GetEasters (@Year = 2018, @Day = 'Monday', @CountryID = 1) -- "An insufficient number of parameters were supplied..."
     -- Evaluation
     SELECT @TestResult = IIF(@RequiredResult = @@ROWCOUNT,1,0)
     -- Set unit-test EndTime
     SET @UnitTestEnd = GETDATE()
     -- Log
     INSERT INTO @Result (TestName,TestResult,TestStart,TestEnd) VALUES (@TestName,@TestResult,@UnitTestStart,@UnitTestEnd)
```

to a scalar function which is defined as

```
CREATEFUNCTION [dim].[GetEasters](@Year AS INTEGER,@Day VARCHAR(15),@CountryID TINYINT)
RETURNS INT
```

The unit test parser raises an error

> "An insufficient number of parameter were supplied..."

This works fine:

```
DECLARE @Result int
SET @Result = dim.GetEasters(2018, 'Monday', 1)
SELECT @Result
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on the small information, I can't see anything wrong. Could you post the code for `dim.GetEasters`?

Comment: What's `@Year = 2018` supposed to do? You can't use named parameters in a function invocation, you can only pass them by position. Pass either `@Year` or `2018`. (But AFAICT, that *should* have given you a syntax error, not "an insufficient number of parameters").

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's correct, I've just figured that out myself. There should be no Year = ....

Comment: You do not need to repeat variables again @Year, you have to simply pass the values

Comment: Looks to me like maybe you should consider replacing that scalar function with an inline table valued function. It is far more flexible and faster than a scalar function. Post the contents of that function and we can make this a LOT easier for you.